# Platform Event Trigger Flow - Flow Execution Error Event

Tags: platform-event, create-records

**Scenario:** I have created a Flow that is triggered by the `Flow Execution Error Event`. So, if any Flow encounters any errors, this Flow will create a log of that error as records in the Error Log Object.

The problem is record(error log) is not created in the object. Need Help on this. Note: I'm a beginner
[image]

Testing:

[image]
[image]

Comment: is your platform event gets fired at all? How are you verifying that?

Comment: I'm testing this Platform event by not inputting the name field required in the screen flow I've created. I've attached the image for your reference!